# How to run html files along with php files on android or pc (Windows)?

Tags: php, html, forms

As I am a beginner in coding,  I just made some html files but want some codes to process the inputs so I got to know about php files which is capable of processing inputs of html.So I made three php files for processing html inputs. As I mentioned before, I am beginner so I don't know how the files run. Whenever I try to submit my html inputs it always shows "file is not supported ". So how can I run html along with php files in my computer ? And if it is successful then could I run it on my android device?

Comment: I suggest you try Javascript instead of PHP. This way you will be able to run the code on the user's device instead of on a server.

Answer (score 2):

In order to run php script you should have php interpreter installed on your system and also a web server. I suggest you to install Wamp or Xamp on your pc. These softwares have all you need in one package. Then you can achieve your goal. About the second part, running on android, there is not a proper way of doing that cause php is a scripting language for developing web applications not mobile apps. If you want to make an app for android you should use `Kotlin`, `Java` or other options.